Open back bathroom vanity on a mid-century bathroom
I recently purchased a new bathroom vanity to replace our existing 1963 one.  The problem is, most of these new vanities come "Open back".  If I was installing over an existing wall, not an issue however, the original vanity was actually "built into" the space by the builders.  It was fabricated to fit into the wall and floor tiling and had a back to it, but the new one does not.  I mean, you have to give the OG builders creds because it could not have been easy to install, but it does present me with the issue of how best to "fill in" that back space to cover the open, exposed wall interior for a more aesthetically pleasing finish.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated on the best way to accomplish this!  Thanks in advance!    

You could fit almost anything over the existing wall surface including:

Drywall (sheet rock)
Thin plywood
Plastic sheeting material
Hard board (masonite)
Cement board

Alternatively you could extend the lip that goes across the back lower edge of the cabinet up the sides and across the top and then use that as a backer to install a false back to the cabinet. That could also be any of the above material selections as well but the thin plywood may be the best.
Either solution will require some careful measuring to make the cutouts to go around the water lines and drain line that project from the wall. For ease of working around these it may be desirable to make the back in two pieces.

This is all VERY good advice and suggestions.  I'll be researching the possibilities.  I'm very grateful for you taking the time to respond.  Best to you.

You're asking a decor/opinion question, that might get shut down PDQ but here's an answer I think is objectively correct in this forum:
If you are doing this DIY, it's a good opportunity to practice/improve your skills at whatever method you'd like to learn in a project that only you will ever see.

Cabinet wall: Buy a piece of white melamine board and attach it to the cabinet walls near the back, with cutouts or a hatch for the pipes.
Wall wall: Cut out the existing wall and replace it with new drywall, patch and paint.
Tile it with cheap white tiles.

Gain from the experience in a project that aesthetically is not very important.

Hello.  Sorry, first time using this forum, (I'm a huge fan already tho), and I need to better educate myself on what should and should not be posed as a question.  I'll learn.  Thanks so much for taking the time to respond.  TILING, I even have some white subway tile left over from another project and didn't consider this option.  I'll definitely be taking some additional thought!  Best to you!

You received a couple of good answers with excellent options. I will offer another.
Do  Nothing
Any attempt to cover the wall will require either a substantial time trying to work in a cramped and uncomfortable place. Or removal of work that is already done. Followed by careful measuring and cutting and placement of something that may or may not fit. All for the purpose of covering something that very few people will ever see.
Whatever you decide, Good Luck to you.

Thank you so much for responding.  We're looking to sell the home so, didn't want to leave it exposed.  If we weren't moving, I'm with you, it's not an issue for me.  Thanks again.  Have a great day.
